# Firefox и подключаемые шрифты

Tags: вёрстка, firefox, шрифты

Firefox не хочет отображать шрифт. Chrome, Safari и Opera отображают нормально. Делаю так:

```
<head>
    <link href="http://allfont.ru/css/?fonts=cyrillicold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

А в CSS соответственно просто пишу:

```
font-family: "CyrillicOld", Arial, sans-serif;
```

Может и не самый лучший вариант - подключать вот так. Лучше было бы залить шрифт в папку сайта и подключать через CSS с `@font-face`. Но переделывать очень не хочется. Подскажите, что можно с этим сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите логи Firefox (Сtrl+Shift+J). Может ругаться на файл шрифта или его формат. Кстати, какая версия Firefox?

Comment: @tutankhamun В логах не ругается. Версия 36.0.4 для OS X

Comment: @tutankhamun причем если нажать Исследовать элемент, выбрать текст, навести на font-family, всплывет текст "the quick brown fox..." написанный правильным шрифтом, то есть инспектором firefox шрифт видит

Comment: а не запрещено ли в настройках *firefox* использование загружаемых шрифтов?

Answer (score 1):

Текст такой должен быть?

[image: <Большой Тестер?]

Если да, то у вас другой тег затирает этот.

И еще один косяк при такой загрузке: при слабой скорости интернета буквы моргают. Сначала стандартный шрифт, потом только подгружается этот шрифт.

Делал на Firefox 38.0.5.